# Automate searching of pages such as Wikipedia

Tags: r, excel, web-scraping

my question is rather general and not quite specific to wikipedia only, I would like to know is there a way to automate gneration and selection of search results. **To give an eample of what I intend:** 
Let's say I'd like to write articles about American Food and I'd like to read information, such as ingredients, texture, cuisine(County-wise), preparation methods, etc. about approximately 500 different American foods. Let's say these are all available on Wiki too and I have an excel sheet with the names of these dishes and columns specifying their properties. But I dont want to manually look up these dishes/food-iems, can I automate this process? I am looking for some general guidance, some open-source links, some pseudo-code or algorithmic approach to this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

**P.S.:** It'd be great if the logic had some links to help in carrying it out using R, since the other aspects of my project have already been built in R. Also i'd like to broaden my searches to include other major information gathering sites/search engines.

Comment: Wikipedia offers an API, which you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it relatively  quickly with use of the `WikipediR` package:

```
require(WikipediR)
phrs <- c("car","house")
j <- 1
for (i in phrs) {
    pgs[j] <- page_content("en", "wikipedia", page_name = i, as_wikitext = TRUE)
    j <- j + 1
}
```

The solution rather fortuitously assumes that your *food names* correspond to the page names on Wikipedia. Most probably this won't be the case for all the items. You may consider using the `pages_in_category` in order to source more pages at once.  I presume that I would fist match my list against `pages_in_category` for a given category *(foods)* and if the number of errors is insignificant progressed to matching the data.